# How do I generate Typescript types with Prisma?

Tags: javascript, typescript, prisma

I'm working on a web app that uses NextJS and Prisma. I've created the Prisma schema and ran `npx prisma generate` to generate the relevant types based on the schema. This seems to be working but when I check the types that are being generated they don't look as I expected and how they are described in the Prisma docs.

See the following example. I have the following model in my Prisma schema:

```
model Recipe {
  id          Int                    @id @default(autoincrement())
  title       String
  description String
  published   Boolean
  featured    Boolean                @default(false)
  ingredients IngredientsOnRecipes[]
  steps       Step[]
  createdAt   DateTime               @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt   DateTime               @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
}
```

And when I import the generated type in one of my pages using `import { Recipe } from '@prisma/client';`, This is what I see:

```
type Recipe = $Result.DefaultSelection<Prisma.$RecipePayload<$Extensions.DefaultArgs>>
```

My issue with this is that if I try to access an attribute that doesn't exist on my type, it doesn't show me a warning or error. Is there a way to get a TS type that looks like this:

```
type Recipe = {
  id: string;
  title: string
  description: string;
  // rest of the properties
}
```

Edit: here is an example of what I meant:

```
import { Recipe } from '@prisma/client';

const RecipeCard = ({ recipe }: { recipe: Recipe }) => {
  const nonExistentProperty = recipe.fakeProperty;
  return <></>;
};
```

The code above runs without warnings or errors.

Edit2:

Here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: could you share your tsconfig file ?

Comment: Sure, I have just edited the post with the tsconfig file. Thank you for having a look!

Comment: Could you try with those parameters, I setup a small environment to mimic yours and get exactly what you want (and I expected)
```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016" ,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true ,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
    "strict": true ,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Changing `module` to `commonjs` seems to do the trick. Alternatively, changing `moduleResolution` to `node` also worked. I'll do further research to check why that works. Many thanks again, if you want to add an answer to the post I'm happy to mark it as accepted, I'll add it it otherwise. Cheers!

Comment: I would, but first I'd like to understand why. drop me a note once you got further explanation :)